# User in two roles with rows security filters and object-level security filters

Tags: ssas, tabular, ssas-2017

I am implementing a dynamic filter in roles that I have in my SSAS Tabular cube. I have a user that is in two different roles.

If I test my data using this user only in one role everything returns as expected, but if the user is in two different roles I get the following error.

> The combination of active roles results in a dynamic security
> configuration that is currently not supported. Please contact the
> administrator of the database to resolve this issue. (Microsoft SQL
> Server 2017 Analysis Services)

I have rows security filters and object-level security filters.

This error appears to anyone? Anyone knows how to pass through this issue?

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently not possible to have a user in multiple roles for row and object level security with dynamic filters.

You can, however, combine both and more into one role. As long as the user is only in one role and all his security is done there it works.